# curl tftp transfer timeout

Tags: curl, libcurl, tftp

I'm using `libcurl 7.25` version, and I have used `curlopt_low_speed_limit` and `curlopt_low_speed_time` options to limit the tftp transfer time. But the curl does not timeout within the specified time and my program remains there. I made sure the curl_easy_setopt api returns curle_ok.
The same program works in `libcurl 7.33` version and the tftp transfer timesout.
Can you please let me why the options are not supported in 7.25 version. Any missing patches?or Am I missing anything?

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 85L);`
```

Answer (score 1):

The [changelog for 7.33.0](http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_33_0) mentions:

```
TFTP: make the CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED* options work
```

.... meaning that they were not working before that but are expected to work from then on. The exact commit that fixed this bug is [here](https://github.com/bagder/curl/commit/4bea91).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have patched the tftp.c diffs along with "#1310 TFTP connection takes CURLOPT_TIMEOUT seconds to time out, not CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT" patch. But still tftp transfer does not timeout. Verified Curl_speedcheck() and is same in both versions. Do you think any other changes might effect? Thanks again.

Comment: Given your description, that sounds likely.